# dbt macros, how to use table in query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, jinja2, dbt

I am trying to write the macro below that creates a checksum column less specified values - but what values should be input for table as the below does not work ( in context of jinja/macros/dbt)

```
{% macro generate_checksum(source) %}

SELECT HASH(*) AS hash_value
          FROM (SELECT * EXCLUDE (a, b, f, c, d, e, z, g) 
                from {{source}} ) 

{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. You could pass a [Relation](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-classes#relation) as an argument to your macro. You could leave your macro as-is, and then call it in your model file with:

   ```sql
   {{ generate_checksum(ref('some_model')) }}
   {# or use source() or this in place of ref() above #}
   ```
2. You could pass a string into your macro, and make the call to `ref` inside your macro. This would lock you into a specific type of relation (e.g., only `ref`, not `source` or `this`). Your macro becomes:

   ```sql
   {% macro generate_checksum(model_name) %}

   SELECT HASH(*) AS hash_value
         FROM (SELECT * EXCLUDE (a, b, f, c, d, e, z, g) 
               from {{ ref(model_name) }} ) 

   {% endmacro %}
   ```

   and you call it in your model file with a string literal:

   ```sql
   {{ generate_checksum('some_model') }}
   ```